# Increasing current from a linear regulator IC

Tags: circuit-design, bjt, darlington

I'm designing a device that will use a common "yellow" 20V tool lithium battery pack (which I know contains an array of 18650 cells, and is actually an 18V pack,) both for its internal operations using a 5V regulator, as well as outputting ~12-14V at high current, maybe 20A.  The latter is where I have a question.

I intend to use a [STMicro PB137ACV](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00001634-1795697.pdf) linear regulator to maintain a constant 13.7V, but its rated maximum current is only 1.5A, and I need maybe 20A at this voltage.

My best guess is to use BJTs ([STMicro TIP35](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00195733-1796717.pdf)) to create a current amplifier.  Specifically, a Darlington pair with additional BJTs to increment the current amplification.  The schematic below is what I have so far:

[image: current amplifier schematic]

I got this idea from [ElecCircuit.com](https://www.eleccircuit.com/high-current-12v-30a25a20a15a-ham-radio-power-supply/) in an article by Apichet Garaipoom.  The concept seems to be sensible, but the writer's broken English and lack of explanation on how it works doesn't give me much confidence.  I tried Googling around for more information on a "BJT current amplifier," but couldn't find anything like this.

Will this circuit do what I want?  Is there a better (or more appropriate) way to get ~12-14VDC @ 20A from an 18V lithium battery pack?

### EDIT:

*Please, no more comments that don't specifically address the question being asked.  It is unhelpful and unprofessional to publicly judge my level of competency or skill based on the question alone.  I realize now that this is a stupid question, and I am ashamed for having asked it, but it's too late for me to delete it.*

Comment: You don't use a linear regulator for currents that high in a battery powered device unless you truly do plan on having a heatsink that is equivalent to a a 100W incandescent bulb just sitting somewhere burning off battery power as heat. Because that's how a linear regulator works: Pull the output current straight through from the input and burn and burn off the excess voltage as heat. It doesn't take a higher voltage at lower current and convert it to a lower voltage at higher current. That's a switching regulator. Use that.

Comment: This will work (unless there's a problem with your circuit; I didn't look in detail), but it will waste huge amounts of power. This is a textbook example of when *not* to use a linear regulator.

Comment: A few questions to better define the problem that needs to be solved.  Is this a one-off?  Do you need/want to design/build the circuit yourself, or it it ok to use off the shelf parts to accomplish the task?  Does it need to be short circuit protected or is it a well disciplined load?  Do you need to consider overdischarge protection or is that handled by battery pack?

Comment: as others have said, ok design if you also want to have an unintentional room heater. Otherwise use  switcher.

Comment: What is the load? Depending on what it is you may skip voltage regulation entirely by just using PWM on it to keep the average voltage where you want it. Especially if it's a motor.

Answer (score 7):

> *Is there a better (or more appropriate) way to get ~12-14VDC @ 20A
> from a 18V lithium battery pack?*

As others have already commented, you need a buck switching regulator like the [LT3840](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3840fa.pdf): -

[image]

This works down to an input supply of 15 volts and, you need to verify that your battery pack does not drop below 15 volts when the 12 volt output is on load. There will be other products that can service your requirements of course and, from other manufacturers such as Texas Instruments.

However, this isn't a design that can be breadboarded or cobbled together in any way at all. In other words, it needs extreme care and attention to PCB layout and component choice to make this work successfully. It's not a hobbyist project but, in all fairness, your requirements implied this to me immediately.

<sub>When answering, it's not just the person raising the question who is the audience but, anyone who might be reading this so, if there's any doubt about someone's qualifications to understand (or implement) a solution, it's probably a good idea to provide suitable warnings. On this occasion, I'm specifically advising that this solution is not for beginners.</sub>

<sub>In addition, if the person raising the question provides **no details** on their profile page about their EE skills, qualifications or experiences then, it's reasonable to assume that the person is a hobbyist or beginner and, as such, appropriate warnings should be given.</sub>

Comment: Not sure why you're worried about whether I intend to "cobble" anything together on a breadboard.  I see the other rude bits were edited out.  I'd mark this as the answer, but I don't think it's deserving.  But a buck regulator would be ideal, not sure why I didn't think of that myself.  Thank you for that much, at least.

Comment: @MatthewClark It's not rude: he's telling the truth. For one, this device, like many high-power ICs, has a buried ground pad for thermal reasons. If you don't know how to reflow solder, it won't work.

Comment: @MatthewClark High power switching converters offer a multitude of failure modes. It helps to wear safety goggles unless one wants the full experience of chunks of chip encapsulant taking a swim in one's copious tears (been there, done that). On the other hand, understand where we come from: you didn't consider DC power dissipation of that thing. It could be an honest goof, but we have honest assumptions **too**. If power dissipation is not an instinctive concept to you, can we assume you can lay this out well? It'd be not only not rude, but prudent of us to assume conservatively!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a switching regulator (highly recommended) and you don't want to deal with the hassle of designing one from a bare controller, you can find PCB mount modules that take care of the tricky stuff.  All you have to add are your preferred connectors, a few capacitors, a trim resistor, and maybe an inductor or two.  If you don't want to do any PCB designing at all, there are chassis mount modules that are ready-to-use with screw terminals.  At that power level, they'll probably be pricey though.

Comment: There are many devices that might be suitable for this, for under $10, such as https://www.ebay.com/itm/111936836128. There are others that can do up to 60A for about $12. However, you may need to add an external feedback circuit to maintain your desired 13.7V. I have one that includes a fwd/rev switch and digital indicator that reads in %PWM. https://www.ebay.com/itm/404057787092

Answer (score 2):

What you've drawn is a common paralleling scheme for current sharing between bipolar transistors. It is important that those transistors are individually operating within their SOA (safe operating area) - see the datasheet for that. Bipolar transistors have not only a rated maximum continuous power dissipation, but also a *derating* for the collector current as the C-E voltage goes up. That means that the dissipated power limit *drops* as the C-E voltage increases. In your case, the voltage will be <10V, so SOA may not be an issue - but always check that.

Another "gotcha" when paralleling transistors is that they **must be held at equal temperature**. That is: they must be well coupled to a large heat sink.

Why is that important? Because hot transistors hog current, i.e. steal current from other paralleled transistors that are cooler. When this hogging is sufficient enough, they thermally run away: they end up taking most of the current from other transistors, exceed their SOA / dissipation limits, and self-destruct. When that happens, usually the other transistors will follow in short order, as they will now carry more of the current.

Mosfets don't have that problem, so they would be a safer choice here.

The biggest problem, of course, is that this is a linear regulator that will be dropping say 5V at 20A at full load. That's 100W. It'll be wasting 1/3rd of the battery's stored energy as heat, and that heat will be hard to dissipate without either a force air cooled heatsink, or a much larger passively cooled heatsink.

The LT3840 part mentioned in the other answer is a great part indeed, but you could get a usable converter with a few common, low cost parts, and it would be a great learning experience to design it yourself.

A crude switching buck converter - with voltage-mode control - would waste comparably little power compared to the linear regulator.  It would not regulate extremely well, and the output "12V" would be, let's say "automotive grade", i.e. would suffer from load dump transients, and sags on load attach. But for plenty of applications it's enough, and the entire thing can be implemented with one suitable mosfet, a chonky Schottky diode, and a couple of analog building blocks from the 70s (a 555, an op-amp, and a gate driver).

Of course, in modern practice, you just go to eBay or Amazon and buy a Buck DC/DC converter module of suitable specs, and have it done in a bout as long as it takes to solder the wires :)

Don't forget about the fuse for the battery, unless you want a fire!